# Optimize a tile rendering algorithm for Swing Canvas

Tags: java, swing, kotlin, canvas

I have an algorithm that I use to render a text GUI using Swing's Canvas, it looks like this in practice:

[image]

My goal is to reach `60` frames per second for a full HD grid with `8x8` (in pixel) tiles. Right now a full-screen grid composed of `16x16` tiles (1920x1080) renders with `60`, but `8x8` tiles have abysmal speed.

I profiled my algorithm and fixed the bottlenecks but now I've reached the limits of Swing itself. This application works with layers composed of `Tile` objects (with a corresponding `Position`) so you can imagine a whole thing as a 3D map composed of `Tile`s with `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates.

My current algorithm works like this:

- I fetch the `Renderable` objects. These are text gui components, layers, etc.
- I render them onto a `FastTileGraphics` object (this uses arrays for speed).
- I divide them into chunks according to the parallelism parameter to achieve parallel decomposition of work.
- I group the `Tile`s into vertical vectors (I do this because I need to support transparency and tiles can be rendered on top of each other).
- If an opaque tile is encountered I overwrite the list since in that case I only need to render a single `Tile` at that position.
- I render the tiles onto `BufferedImage`s in parallel.
- Then I render these images onto the `Canvas`.

The implementation looks like this:

```kotlin
override fun render() {
    val now = SystemUtils.getCurrentTimeMs()

    val bs: BufferStrategy = canvas.bufferStrategy // this is a regular Swing Canvas object

    val parallelism = 4
    val interval = tileGrid.width / (parallelism - 1)
    val tilesToRender = mutableListOf<MutableMap<Position, MutableList<Pair<Tile, TilesetResource>>>>()
    0.until(parallelism).forEach { _ ->
        tilesToRender.add(mutableMapOf())
    }

    val renderables = tileGrid.renderables // TileGrid supplies the renderables that contain the tiles
    for (i in renderables.indices) {
        val renderable = renderables[i]
        if (!renderable.isHidden) {
            val graphics = FastTileGraphics(
                    initialSize = renderable.size,
                    initialTileset = renderable.tileset,
                    initialTiles = emptyMap()
            )
            renderable.render(graphics)
            graphics.contents().forEach { (tilePos, tile) ->
                val finalPos = tilePos + renderable.position
                val idx = finalPos.x / interval
                tilesToRender[idx].getOrPut(finalPos) { mutableListOf() }
                if (tile.isOpaque) {
                    tilesToRender[idx][finalPos] = mutableListOf(tile to renderable.tileset)
                } else {
                    tilesToRender[idx][finalPos]?.add(tile to renderable.tileset)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    canvas.bufferStrategy.drawGraphics.configure().apply {
        color = Color.BLACK
        fillRect(0, 0, tileGrid.widthInPixels, tileGrid.heightInPixels)
        tilesToRender.map(::renderPart).map { it.join() }.forEach { img ->
            drawImage(img, 0, 0, null)
        }
        dispose()
    }

    bs.show()
    lastRender = now
}

private fun renderPart(
        tilesToRender: MutableMap<Position, MutableList<Pair<Tile, TilesetResource>>>
): CompletableFuture<BufferedImage> = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
    val img = BufferedImage(
            tileGrid.widthInPixels,
            tileGrid.heightInPixels,
            BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT
    )
    val gc = img.graphics.configure()
    for ((pos, tiles) in tilesToRender) {
        for ((tile, tileset) in tiles) {
            renderTile(
                    graphics = gc,
                    position = pos,
                    tile = tile,
                    tileset = tilesetLoader.loadTilesetFrom(tileset)
            )
        }
    }
    img
}

private fun Graphics.configure(): Graphics2D {
    this.color = Color.BLACK
    val gc = this as Graphics2D
    gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF)
    gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_SPEED)
    gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE)
    gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_OFF)
    gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_OFF)
    gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_SPEED)
    gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY)
    return gc
}

private fun renderTile(
        graphics: Graphics2D,
        position: Position,
        tile: Tile,
        tileset: Tileset<Graphics2D>
) {
    if (tile.isNotEmpty) {
        tileset.drawTile(tile, graphics, position)
    }
}
```

`Renderable` looks like this, it just accepts a `TileGraphics` for rendering:

```kotlin
interface Renderable : Boundable, Hideable, TilesetOverride {

    /**
     * Renders this [Renderable] onto the given [TileGraphics] object.
     */
    fun render(graphics: TileGraphics)
}
```

`TileGraphics` looks like this:

```kotlin
interface TileGraphics {

    val tiles: Map<Position, Tile>

    fun draw(
            tile: Tile,
            drawPosition: Position
    )
}
```

and `Tileset` is an object that loads the textures from the filesystem and draws individual tiles on a surface (`Graphics2D` in our case):

```kotlin
interface Tileset<T : Any> {
    fun drawTile(tile: Tile, surface: T, position: Position)
}
```

`surface` here represents the grapics object we use to draw. This is necessary because there is also a LibGDX renderer that works differently. There are also multiple kinds of `Tileset`s, this is how a regular monospace font is rendered:

```kotlin
override fun drawTile(tile: Tile, surface: Graphics2D, position: Position) {
    val s = tile.asCharacterTile().get().character.toString()

    val fm = surface.getFontMetrics(font)

    val x = position.x * width
    val y = position.y * height

    surface.font = font
    surface.color = tile.backgroundColor.toAWTColor()
    surface.fillRect(x, y, resource.width, resource.height)
    surface.color = tile.foregroundColor.toAWTColor()
    surface.drawString(s, x, y + fm.ascent)
}
```

This algorithm runs for `~22ms`.

I've profiled the whole thing and a major bottleneck is the **drawing** part:

```kotlin
tilesToRender.map(::renderPart).map { it.join() }.forEach { img ->
    drawImage(img, 0, 0, null)
}
```

If I remove those 3 lines I get `~5ms` runtime (so drawing takes `~17ms`).

I also noticed that parallel decomposition doesn't help at all. If I remove all parallelism I get similar results. Increasing parallelism results in an FPS drop.

The second biggest bottleneck is the **grouping** code (the `graphics.contents().forEach { (tilePos, tile) ->` part), it takes around `~4.5ms`.

The numbers in total:

```
21.696576799999985  <-- all
5.328403500000007   <-- without drawing
4.575503500000005   <-- without any java 2d graphics operations
0.08593370000000009 <-- without grouping
```

How can I optimize this algorithm? The only part that's mandatory is rendering the renderables: `renderable.render(graphics)` but I already optimized it and it only takes `~0.8ms`, so that's negligible.

Answer (score 2):

You could either use the real Java console, but that would mean you have to recreate your entire application.

If you really insist to use Swing, I would do it in another way. Create some custom `print()` methode for printing ASCII-symbols into a buffered-image, scale this image and use it as background for just a single AWT/Swing component. After that you create a custom actionListener for this AWT/Swing component. Now you've created a simple terminal, which will perform much faster. By the way, you also have to rewrite most of your application in this scenario.

PS your application looks cool ;-)

Comment: The application is written in a way that it doesn't matter **how** I render. I could write a terminal application with no problem if I wanted. How would this `print` method look like? I already render into a `BufferImage` that I then draw onto the `Canvas`. Why would this be faster? I don't want to scale the image because I want to preserve the crispness of my glyphs.

Comment: You are using a ton of objects, just for one screen. The print `method()` would be some kind of copy of `System.out.print()`, but instead of printing out to console, it draws directly onto a buffered image in a well defined way (You have to define it to your targeted look&feel.). The important thing is, it does that without using any object, (besides 1 graphics object). For example _your_ `print()` would draw each character in a 7pixel x 5pixel rectangular with some custom font. You draw 80 characters in one line, do this for 25 lines and voila you have some kind of vt-100-terminal dimension.

Comment: PS resizing an image in a linear way lets your image remain its "crispness". Just use a scale factor which is a natural number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation PPS to answer your question _"Why would this be faster?"_ - You are reducing a lot of overhead, which you've created by using tons of objects for rendering a simple image. "Drawing" a simple `int` is faster than calculating, rendering, drawing an entire _object_.

Comment: Right now there is literally no overhead by creating all these objects (`~0.06ms`). You can see that the 2 bottlenecks are the **grouping** and the **rendering**. I would be happy if I could optimize the rendering part, but I'm not sure how your suggestion would apply to my code.

Comment: My suggestion don't apply to your code. Your chosen way is unfortunately an inefficient way to achieve your task. You may try to use AWT-components instead of Swing and may also override their `paint()` method. AWT is faster than Swing but has less features. For example you need to implement a double-image-buffer by yourself. This would be doable in less effort, because Swing is mostly compatible to AWT. AWT-components are also able to be **hardware accelerated** (Swing too, but it has still more overhead.), but this makes your app often also platform dependet. **Also use an IndexColorModel.**

Comment: So first, try to use **hardware acceleration** for your current program. After that try to implement an **IndexColorModel** with maximal 256 different colors, this may increase speed. After that you may try to use **AWT** instead of **Swing**. You may override `paint()` method directly too. Otherwise do like in my first answers and create some kind of virtual terminal without tons of objects.

Comment: Do you have a code example for this?

Answer (score 2):

Example for an **IndexColorModel**.

```
/* START */
public static final class GUI {
    public static final Color BLACK =   new Color(0x00, 0x00, 0x00);    
    public static final Color MAROON =  new Color(0x80, 0x00, 0x00);
    public static final Color GREEN =   new Color(0x00, 0x80, 0x00);
    public static final Color OLIVE =   new Color(0x80, 0x80, 0x00);
    public static final Color NAVY =    new Color(0x00, 0x00, 0x80);
    public static final Color PURPLE =  new Color(0x80, 0x00, 0x80);
    public static final Color TEAL =    new Color(0x00, 0x80, 0x80);
    public static final Color SILVER =  new Color(0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0);
    public static final Color GRAY =    new Color(0x80, 0x80, 0x80);
    public static final Color RED =     new Color(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
    public static final Color LIME =    new Color(0x00, 0xFF, 0x00);
    public static final Color YELLOW =  new Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00);
    public static final Color BLUE =    new Color(0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
    public static final Color FUCHSIA = new Color(0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF);
    public static final Color AQUA =    new Color(0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    public static final Color WHITE =   new Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    
    public static final Color[] COLOR_ARRAY = {
        BLACK, MAROON, GREEN, OLIVE, NAVY, PURPLE, TEAL, SILVER,
        GRAY, RED, LIME, YELLOW, BLUE, FUCHSIA, AQUA, WHITE
    };
    
    public static final byte[] COLOR_ARRAY_RED_COMPONENTS = {
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[0].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[1].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[2].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[3].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[4].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[5].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[6].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[7].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[8].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[9].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[10].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[11].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[12].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[13].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[14].getRed(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[15].getRed()
    };
    public static final byte[] COLOR_ARRAY_GREEN_COMPONENTS = {
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[0].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[1].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[2].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[3].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[4].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[5].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[6].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[7].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[8].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[9].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[10].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[11].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[12].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[13].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[14].getGreen(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[15].getGreen()
    };
    public static final byte[] COLOR_ARRAY_BLUE_COMPONENTS = {
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[0].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[1].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[2].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[3].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[4].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[5].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[6].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[7].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[8].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[9].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[10].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[11].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[12].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[13].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[14].getBlue(),
        (byte)COLOR_ARRAY[15].getBlue()
    };
    
    public static final IndexColorModel INDEX_COLOR_MODEL = new IndexColorModel(
            4, 16, /* 4bit color range, 16 unique colors */
            COLOR_ARRAY_RED_COMPONENTS,
            COLOR_ARRAY_GREEN_COMPONENTS,
            COLOR_ARRAY_BLUE_COMPONENTS
    );
}
/* END */
```

For example this IndexColorModel uses only 16 different colors, while using 4bit per color and a 24bit color palette.
When applied onto a BufferedImage, like:

`new BufferedImage(640, 480, TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED, INDEX_COLOR_MODEL)`

It reduces maximal color space to 4bit per color and the chosen 16 different colors. Effectively reducing image data size and thus increasing performance.

An advantage of this INDEX_COLOR_MODEL for your application would be, that you would've just to change the color palette to adjust your application colors. Which is much faster, than to repaint all components in a different color from 24bit RGB-color-space (24bit RGB-color-space is a defacto standard for using BufferedImage in Java.).

You may draw in any color to this INDEX_COLOR_MODEL BufferedImage, your chosen color will be automaticly adjusted to the colorspace of your BufferedImage. But it's adviceable to directly use the colors of your colorspace in the first place, because that's a bit faster.

I suggest you read the Java API documentation regarding this feature:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/IndexColorModel.html

The other functions (**hardware acceleration**, **AWT**, overriding `paint()`) are more or less easy to implement. Search and read some tutorials.

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me. All I see is a black screen and no error message. The problem is that I need to support transparency and dynamic colors since my users can choose their own colors.

Comment: I suggest you read about what a color palette is. For what do you need transparency? Your users may choose their own colors too, by changing the color palette. `public static final Color BLACK = new Color(0x00, 0x00, 0x00);` <- this is a 24bit color. Just use something like `public static Color userColor = new Color(0x12, 0x34, 0x56);`. When you use a "limited/indexed" color space, your "input" colors may become "deformed". What this means: If your "input" color is very dark, it might become just _BLACK_ in the "limited/indexed" color space. Try to use the predefined colors, instead of custom.

Comment: I tried your example but it didn't work. I just saw an empty black screen without error messages.